# PHP : Execute a form validation with regular expression then submit

Tags: php, regex, validation

The script below works fine to validate inputs. the issues is after validation i want to send the data to another script so it can stored in the DB. How can i edit the action attribute to get what i want ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
$nameErr = "";
$name = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example :</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want them to submit the form twice? First to validate it, and then to send it to the second script that processes it? What if they modify the inputs after you've validated it?

Comment: You shouldn't call `htmlspecialchars` when validating, you should only use that when you're displaying data.

Comment: What i want exactly is this :
1. validate inputs.
2. if everything is OK, redirect to the process script.
3. if not back to the html page with error mesaage.

Comment: Redirects don't send POST parameters.

Comment: I know this is why i'm stuck here... any suggestions ? Thank you by the way :D

Comment: Most people just do the validation in the script that processes the data, they don't split it across two different scripts.

Comment: @Barmar The request is reasonable, especially in multi-part forms or when front-end and server-side validation is required. It is trivial to store the post data in a session and perform the necessary redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a session:

```
session_start();
```

Store the form data in the session:

```
$_SESSION['form_data'] = $_POST;
```

Redirect to the new script:

```
header("Location: new_script.php");
```

In the new script, retrieve the data from the session and insert it into the database. See [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for details.